# Как расчитать цену, если известна только текущая цена и процент?

Tags: javascript, математика, проценты

Пример:
На сайте в карточке товара прописана текущая цена изделия, например - 1000. И прописана скидка - 50% (Т.е эта цена уже со скидкой 50%)

Как посчитать цену без скидки, если известно только текущая цена (1000) и скидка (50)?

```
Цена товара 1000
Старая цена ?р должна быть 2000
Скидка 50%
```

Comment: `новаяцена = стараяцена * (100 - скидка) / 100` — тривиальное уравнение

Comment: @AlexeyTen нужно получить как раз таки старую цену, а не новую.

Comment: Вы не можете подставить известные значения куда надо, икс в качестве неизвестного и решить уравнение?

Comment: Для примера `1000 = x * (100 - 50) / 100` — найти икс, задача для пятикласника

Comment: @AlexeyTen Не знаю, у меня может программа в школе другая была или не помню. В кратце надо это решить `x - 50% = 1000`

Comment: ну может не пятиклассника, а 6-классника. Про процент нужно просто понимать что `x - N%` это то же самое что `x * (100 - N) / 100` ну или эквивалентно `x * (1 - N / 100)`

Comment: Это что, в школе проценты уже не учат?... вроде как, если верить Интернету, 5 класс...

Answer (score 0):

Новая цена это `100 - скидка %` от старой цены. В данном случае получается, что 1000 это 50%. Получить отсюда 100% элементарно.

Comment: Всё равно не понял как это считать. Например цена 900 и скидка 10%. Как получить 1000?

Comment: @steep Вам формулу в комментарии к вопросу привели: **900 / (1 - 10/100) = 900 / 0.9 = 1000**